# Bootstrap header layout for logo and menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using latest bootstrap version and trying to achieve similar look at the image below:

```
http://i.imgur.com/Gihxlat.png
```

The problem is logo on the left overlaps with row one and row two. What is the best way to handle this without messing up responsiveness. Do you think I should make logo absolute or are there any other solutions that would work better.

The code I have so far is something like this :

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4" id="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="search">SEARCH</div>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="buton">BUTON1 + BUTON2</div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4" id="menu">MENU ITEM 01  | MENU ITEM 02  | MENU ITEM 03  |MENU ITEM 04  |</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
#logo {
    background-color:gray;
    height:50px;
}
#search {
    background-color:aqua;
}
#buton {
    background-color:pink;
}
#menu {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Tankucukhas/njyg745h/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create HTML grouping in differnt way to achieve this. Below is the fiddle and code to achieve this.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/se30o1sz/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4" id="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="col-md-4 pull-right" id="search">SEARCH</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 pull-right" id="buton">BUTON1 + BUTON2</div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right" id="menu">MENU ITEM 01  | MENU ITEM 02  | MENU ITEM 03  |MENU ITEM 04  |</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add .clearfix to your code below the logo and below "Button 1 + Button 2":

```
<div class="clearfix hidden-md></div>
```

JS Fiddle link: [Added clearfix](http://jsfiddle.net/njyg745h/3/)